# Dependencies from a .deb file

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dependencies

Given just a .deb file, how do I get the list of dependencies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to run:

```
$ dpkg --info <blah>.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

This should (among other things) list the "depends" section of the package description.

```
$ dpkg -p <package_name>
```

Comment: Except the OP wants the info out of a .deb file, not an installed package.